# Сортировка результирующего набора в обратном порядке

Tags: mysql

Код примерно следующий:

```
string query = SELECT * FROM table WHERE (блабла); 
int length=StringLen(query); 
mysql_real_query(mysql,query,length); 
int result = mysql_store_result(mysql); 
int numOfRows = mysql_num_rows(result); 
 for (int i=numOfRows; i>=0; i-- ) 
 {row = mysql_fetch_row(result); 
 ...}
```

Вопрос вот в чём: нужно заставить `mysql_fetch_row` обрабатывать полученный набор в обратном порядке.

Comment: да, "... ORDER BY `сортируемое_поле` DESC;" можно было бы использовать, если было бы какое то перечисляемое поле, но таких в таблице нет(делать еще и перечисление - в моём случае невероятный гемор..). нужно чтоб mysql_fetch_row() обрабатывал полученный результат в обратном порядке. такое вобще возможно?

Answer (score 1):

без сортировки говорить о порядке данных в селекте опасно.
но если устраивает порядок, то можно

```
set @a=0;
SELECT * FROM (SELECT @a:=@a+1 AS a, * FROM  xxxx WHERE rrrrrrr) AS s  ORDER BY s.a   DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

думаю самое простое решение, это в селекте вместо "*" перечислить поля как тебе надо.

Comment: он не про поля, а про полученный набор записей

Answer (score 0):

```
string query = SELECT * FROM table WHERE (блабла) ORDER BY чего_то DESC;
```

DESC определят что сортировать нужно в обратном порядке

Comment: mysql_fetch_row() обрабатывает один ряд результата, на который ссылается переданный указатель. Ряд возвращается в виде массива. Каждая колонка располагается в следующей ячейке массива, начиная с нулевого индекса